# Writing to the log file of an error associated with the time of its occurrence

Tags: python, logging

```
def logging(func):
    from datetime import datetime

    def wrapper():
        try:
            print(f'{func.__name__} - {func.__doc__}')
            func()
        except Exception as e:
            e = f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")} - {func.__name__} - {e}'
            print(e)
            with open('function_errors.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.seek(0, 2)
                f.write(e)

    return wrapper()

# test
@logging
def zerodiv():
    """It is ZeroDivisionError"""
    x = 1 / 0


@logging
def varname():
    """It is NameError"""
    x = y


@logging
def imok():
    """Here OK !"""
    x = 'Tom Cat'


zerodiv()
varname()
imok()
```

Tell me how to improve logging and writing errors to a file. It is necessary that all errors are recorded in a log file with a date.
At the moment I only have one error logged.

Comment: Open the file in append (`'a'`) mode instead.

Comment: Configure Python's built-in logging to log to a file! https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename = logname,
                    filemode = 'a',
                    format = '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                    level = logging.DEBUG)

try:
    # code goes here
except:
    logging.exception('')
```

This should log any errors in the code to the log file.

Comment: Well, how then to issue a log entry in this form? 09.08.2022 18:53:41 - zerodiv - division by zero
09.08.2022 18:53:41 - varname - name 'y' is not defined